# How to disable sublime text 4 Context-Aware Suggestions

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext4

In sublime text 4, it will suggest context word, I want disable that feature.

for example,  I type `wh`, I will get a "while snippet".

[image]

when file have "while" word, I type `wh`,I will get "while" word and "while snippet",I have to move down to select "while snippet".

[image]

`"auto_complete_use_index": false,` do not work.

Is there a way to disable the first "while" word.

Comment: Not sure you can (using build 4113). However if you type the whole 1st word (`while`, `for`, ...) the first suggestion will disappear and you'll be on the snippet again. Kinda defeats the purpose but still better than disabling the feature...

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to inhibit word/buffer completions entirely, you can create a plugin like the following (Tools menu -> Developer -> New Plugin... and replace the placeholder with the following):

```py
import sublime, sublime_plugin


class InhibitWordCompletionsEventListener(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
    def on_query_completions(self, view, prefix, locations):
        return sublime.CompletionList([sublime.CompletionItem.command_completion('', 'noop')], sublime.INHIBIT_WORD_COMPLETIONS)
```

Be sure to save it in the folder ST recommends (i.e. `Packages/User/`) with a `.py` extension.

Then, when you type `wh`, ST won't suggest the word `while`, just the Python snippet.

NOTE: this feels like a bit of a hack, it may not work this way in future builds of ST, but I tested on 4125 and it works there.

---

If you *do* want to disable buffer completions entirely, see [How to remove words in the current buffer from Sublime Text 4 autocomplete list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70825799/4473405).

Answer (score 0):

On my test for version 4121，I get the following results：

```
"auto_complete_include_snippets": false, --OK
"auto_complete_use_index": false,  -- no work
"index_files": false,  -- no work
```

Given this, you can try the setting：

```
"auto_complete_include_snippets"
```

Comment: That is not work. The setting disable snippets what is I need. And I want to disable things is still there.